# Switch Statement and Functions

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object, switch-statement

This code is meant to create a revised BMI using a switch statement to factor in muscle mass. I can't understand why the switch statement is not working. I've console logged all of the values that are part of the switch statement, but for some reason it always returns the default response. If anyone could give me an insight into why this isn't working, I'd be grateful.

var heightInputFeet = 5;
    var inches = 11;
    var footToMeter = parseFloat((heightInputFeet * 0.3048) + (0.3048 / 12) * inches).toFixed(2);
    var inputWeight = 82;

```
var bench = 30;
var squat = 60;
var curl = 25;
var pullUps = 24;

var liftStats = new Object();
liftStats.bench = bench;
liftStats.squat = squat;
liftStats.curl = curl;
liftStats.pullUps = pullUps;
liftStats.pullUpPower = (pullUps * inputWeight) / 10;

function baseStats() {
    this.height = footToMeter;
    this.weight = inputWeight;
    this.BMI = this.weight / Math.pow(footToMeter, 2);
}
var userStats = new baseStats();

var sum = bench + squat + curl + liftStats.pullUpPower;  // sum equals 311.8

function revisedBMI(n){    //38 - 54
var diff = 450 - n; // 
    switch(diff){
        case (diff < 180 && diff > 120):
            function lower() {
                return liftStats.muscleBMI = userStats.BMI - (diff / 50);
            }
            lower();
            break;
        case (diff > 60 && diff < 120):
            function mid(){
                return liftStats.muscleBMI = userStats.BMI - (diff / 50);
            }
            mid();
            break;
        case (diff < 60 && diff > 0):
            function adv(){
                return liftStats.muscleBMI = userStats.BMI - (diff / 50);
            }
            adv();
            break;
        case (diff < 0):
            function mega(){
                return liftStats.muscleBMI = userStats.BMI - (diff / 50);

            }
            mega();
            break;
        default: console.log("please enter a value...");
            break;
    }
}
revisedBMI(sum);
```

Comment: To clarify a bit more, the function that corresponds to the case should add a new property to the object liftStats, liftStats.muscleBMI. The property in each case should be equal to the userStats.BMI property of the userStats object minus the diff (equal to 450 - the parameter, in this case, sum, which is 311.8), but, as I say, it fails to create this property and instead outputs the default.

Comment: Nice one, cookie monster. Extra points for brevity of response - that's moral points, I have no rep :p

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `case`s are compared to the value in the `switch`. So, you're checking for `diff == (diff < 180 && diff > 120)`, which is either `diff == true` or `diff == false`.

Use if/elses, or `switch(true)`.